# In Middleware why is this value only set once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

So I was testing some middleware and found what was causing my issue.  Here is a very simple explanation.

I have this for example

```
public class AuthMiddleware
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    //have constructor as standard so removed to keep example short as not important

    public async Task Invoke(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _client = GetClientAsync();
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }

    private async Task<HttpClient> GetClientAsync(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        //NOTE: I would expect the _client to be null on every call to this method
        //However once it is created it does not get created again.
        if(_client == null)
        {
            _client = clientFactory.CreateClient("TestClient");
        }
        return _client;
    }
}
```

As for my note `_client` is instance variable and not static so why would it hold an instance on every request and not be null and recreated as expected?

Answer (score 4):

(Convention-based) Middleware in ASP.NET Core is **only** created at startup:

> Middleware is constructed once per application lifetime.

From [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

So instance fields are kept for all requests.

If you need more control over the scope of the middleware, you could use  [Factory-based middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: So created on startup but called per request?

Comment: Yes indeed. To be clear,  `Invoke` / `InvokeAsync` is called for each request